# LTspice DC-blocking capacitor not working

Tags: capacitor, ltspice, dc-blocking

I have been busy with a frequency shift keying modulation circuit in LTspice. The modulator works but I have this horrible DC-offset! I have tried high-pass filters and DC-blocking capacitors but I cannot get it to work correctly. Can someone point out my mistake? I a screenshot of the circuit below. As you see the signal is not oscillating around 0V but instead on top of 0V. My filter or DC-blocking cap work fine when I use a spice signal generator with offset just not on this signal and I don't understand it. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: LTspice circuit with high-pass filter]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The time constant of \$10k\Omega\$ and \$100\mu F\$ is 1s. Your simulation is 5ms long. The high pass filter hasn't had time to settle. Either:

- change the filter to a shorter time constant
- increase the length of the simulation
- put an initial condition on the capacitor

Comment: with LTspice, you can ask it to simulate without output for a while, to settle time constants like this, then start output later.

Comment: @Neil or set sn initial condition